# Multiple audio tracks in mediaelement.js WP plugin?

Tags: mediaelement.js

I am trying to make the audio player display multiple tracks running the mediaelements.js WP plugin. I have tried to use a comma delimited list in the shortcode and this is not working. Do I need to change something in the code somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible at the moment.
Check out this Player

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mp3-jplayer/

Example for multiple tracks:
[mp3-jplayer tracks="myfileA.mp3, myfileB.mp3, myfileC.mp3"]

Hope that helps,
cheers!